# Optimizing SQL query with multiple joins for faster performance

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

com_cards_charge :
[com_cards_charge table(DB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc5zn.png)
com_debt :
[com_debt table(DB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfUVF.png)

some of result:
[Result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOzDF.png)
[Result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZI59.png)

```
SELECT 
      * 
   FROM 
      com_cards_charge, 
      com_debt 
   where 
         com_debt.com_debt_cards_charge_id = com_cards_charge.com_cards_charge_id 
     AND debt_Creditor_type in (0, 15) 
     AND com_cards_charge_deleted = '0'  
   GROUP BY 
      com_cards_charge.com_cards_charge_id  
   order by 
      com_cards_charge_id DESC
```

This query takes more than 6s to load data.
The total rows: 21121.

Thanks for helping me

Comment: wrong tag "jquery"

Comment: Sorry, It's my mistake.

Comment: Need more information. There's nothing specific that can be fixed with this SQL, without knowing more about the tables, specifically how they're indexed.

Comment: The only general tip I can give without knowing more about your tables, is to avoid the use of "select *". It's more efficient to only select the columns you actually need.

Comment: You can see now the tables and some results.

Comment: When asking query optimisation questions, please include the full `CREATE TABLE` statements (as text, not images) and output of `EXPLAIN` for current query. Similarly, sample data and/or expected results should be included in text form.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the two tables.  Please identify each column as to which table it belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, start to write your queries using JOIN showing context relation on how A = B.  Second, add aliases next to your table names in the FROM clause so you can use the shortened version within the rest of the query.  Helps if you are using the same table multiple times in the same query for alternate purposes too.

Next, add the following indexes on your tables

```
table               index on
com_cards_charge   ( com_cards_charge_deleted, com_cards_charge_id )
com_debt           ( com_debt_cards_charge_id, debt_Creditor_type )
```

And updated the query with joins and alias use

```
SELECT 
      * 
   FROM 
      com_cards_charge cc
         JOIN com_debt cd
            on cc.com_cards_charge_id = cd.com_debt_cards_charge_id
           AND cd.debt_Creditor_type in (0, 15) 
   where 
      cc.com_cards_charge_deleted = '0'  
   GROUP BY 
      cc.com_cards_charge_id  
   order by 
      cc.com_cards_charge_id DESC
```

Also, dont paste images to your posts, EDIT and manually type samples of the data (that is important to show context of what you are trying to get).  Same with displaying table structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve speed by specifying columns you need to fetch instead of `SELECT * FROM ...`

Also, using the JOIN keyword in SQL queries can often help improve query optimization

```
SELECT com_cards_charge.col1, com_debt.col2 FROM com_cards_charge JOIN com_debt ON com_debt.col3 = com_cards_charge.col3 WHERE ...
```

These two steps can help you, thank you